# Event scaling does not update coordinates of group internal objects - Fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

**I have 6 objects within a group, but when I scaling I do not update the current coordinates**

I tried to use setCoords(), but it does not work.

I need to get individually left,top, getScaledWidth(),getScaledHeight(). Help me! please

```
     canvas.on('object:scaling', function (e) {
         var obj = e.target;
         //console.log(obj.id);

         if (obj.id === "GroupObject") {
         obj.setCoords();

         console.log(obj.item(1).left);
         console.log(obj.item(1).top);
         console.log(obj.item(1).getScaledHeight());
         console.log(obj.item(1).getScaledWidth());
         }
```